# SQL Compact to Azure SQL Server fails without firewall rule in place

Tags: azure-sql-database

WPF client with SQL Server syncing to Azure SQL Server. Client sync fails unless it's on an IP adddress that I setup an Azure firewall rule for. Of course this renders the client all but useless.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a web api interface between the client and the server.  You should not be distributing your login credentials with your client application.

You web api should contain your server credentials and your users should login and access a rest interface.

This is what I use along side entity framework.
http://www.asp.net/